# Checking Google Sheets values for allowed characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filtering

I'm working on a formula to validate usernames, ensuring they consist only of allowed characters.

I attempted the code below, but it appears to only verify whether the username includes any of the specified characters, so it may also include characters that are not permitted. I also tried excluding unwanted characters, but that didn't work for things like smiley faces.

How can I modify the formula to filter usernames that include only allowed characters?

```
=if(REGEXMATCH(A40,        
"Q|W|E|R|T|Y|U|I|O|P|A|S|D|F|G|H|J|K|L|Z|X|C|V|B|N|M|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|.|_")=True,
"delete","ok")
```

Thanks

Comment: How far did you get with your study of regexes? Did you already learn about anchors like `^` and `$`? Are they supported by the environment you are using?

Comment: well I know what they do but I don't see how to use them here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [start and end of string anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

```cpp
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A40,"^[A-Za-z._]+$"),"Delete","OK")
```

Also, you don't have to list every possible character, if you want the characters from `A` to `Z` you can use `[A-Z]`, similarly, if you want the characters from `a` to `z` you can use `[a-z]`.

If you are using this to filter data, you don't need the `IF`, you can use the `FILTER` function directly.

```cpp
=FILTER(A40,REGEXMATCH(A40,"^[A-Za-z._]+$"))
```

Replace `A40` with the appropriate range.

Comment: Thank you! Though I have question about anchors, aren't they used to match beginning and end of a sequence, and in our case the beginning would be [ABC...], how does it match?

Comment: They match the start/end of the input string, not the regex pattern. For example, If you have `FooBar` in A40, `^` matches right before `F` and `$` matches right after `r`.